# Where should PWA manifest be located for a Django app?

Tags: android, django, progressive-web-apps

I'm working on converting a Django app to a Progressive Web App. Where should the manifest file be located in my directory structure if I [link to the manifest](https://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/#using-a-link-element-to-link-to-a-manifest)? I am thinking of:

```
<!-- Startup configuration -->
<link rel="manifest" href="{% static 'app_name/manifest.webmanifest' %}">
```

I was working through the [lighthouse plug-in](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/) feedback checklist to prep my website for use as a PWA and I ran into the message `No usable web app manifest found on page.`

For Django converting to PWA, is there a preferred convention for this setup?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put the file as long as it is available. Are you sure the manifest URL is valid? Did you open it?

Comment: Just looking for best practice! If it doesn't matter that is cool. I'll test the URL now but I expect it to be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by farooq, the file location for the manifest does not matter as long as the manifest meets all the requirements for [obtaining the manifest](https://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/#dfn-obtaining-the-manifest):

> The steps for obtaining a manifest are given by the following
>   algorithm. The algorithm, if successful, returns a processed manifest
>   and the manifest URL; otherwise, it terminates prematurely and returns
>   nothing. In the case of nothing being returned, the user agent MUST
>   ignore the manifest declaration. In running these steps, a user agent
>   MUST NOT delay the load event.
>
> 1. From the Document of the top-level browsing context, let origin be the
>      Document's origin, **and manifest link be the first link element in tree
>      order whose rel attribute contains the token manifest.**

Therefore, this is fine for a Django Progressive Web App manifest and the file location should be based on project convention:

```
<!-- Startup configuration -->
<link rel="manifest" href="{% static 'app_name/manifest.webmanifest' %}">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Django-simple-pwa just run `pip install django-simple-pwa` then add it to your installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'pwa',
]
```

With this app you don't need to define and serve file such as manifest.json by own every things done automatically.

Then follow these documents:

pypi: https://pypi.org/project/django-simple-pwa/

docs: https://django-simple-pwa.readthedocs.io/fa/latest/

Documents are in Persian language but can translate to your local language with google translate I test it there is no translation problems